# Autoconf spaces in path

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf

I just converted a c++ project to a autotools project and written a few lines in configure.ac from [here](http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/autoconf-2.12/autoconf_2.html). Build fails saying "sh: /home/me/bla: No such file or directory" when my path should be "bla bla". The problem is I didn't write any path anywhere. What shoul I do? Except for renaming the path... Doh!

Comment: Some silly operating systems believe you shouldn't have spaces in names. I'm sure using  `bla_bla` will make everything easier.

Comment: Agreed, but I used a path with spaces to fix issues that someone with this kind of path might encounter. It's not a private project, it's supposed to run on any Linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there are just a few things that you can't do with autoconf and have a path with spaces in the name is one of them.

Comment: I wish ALL C and C++ libraries which supply autoconf scripts for building on Windows were aware of this. Majority of things install in `C:/Program Files` or `C:/Program Files (x86)` and not being able to handle such paths is a big problem.