# Why is there still a «spaces in path» problem with autoconf in 2019 and does anyone know of a patch or a workaround?

Tags: makefile, internationalization, whitespace, filepath, autoconf

Having failed the building of the last version of sagemath, I found out that the problem comes from autoconf, which is, I believe, a very common piece of software. Replacing the path with symlinks doesn't solve the problem since autoconf will find the real path and use it.

I feel hard to believe that yet in 2019, when unicode characters has become so common that one finds them as well in source files as in filenames, that nobody ever solved this problem on such a common piece of code. Having spaces in path might still be considered by some as malpractice, but as @LucianMLI told in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194124/autoconf-spaces-in-path), having the conditions that might causes failure is necessary to detect and correct bad code and make it work on any machine.

So my question : is there a common patch or workaround on this problem, or is there any community working on it or people who know why this problem arises ?

Comment: Mainly, this is a problem of syntax/design of ancient underlying tools, such as m4 or make. And you can't do anything about that, except switching to another toolchain. But then why do you need autotools at all? There is plenty of alternatives.

Comment: I'm not the one who choose to use autotools to build sagemath, and according to my searchs, the problem seem to come from the use of shell script and it is perfectly possible to quote strings to avoid it (I have written functions in bash which solve this problem - If needed, porting the shell script would be a efficient option even if it might at the cost of a little portability which we don't care about since it would just be a work around on a well known program.

Comment: Is it your job to chase space-related errors in 30-years-old system? It will never undergo any significant changes, as too many pieces of software depend on it, and only a few are willing to invest into updating to a newer version.

Comment: @Viktor Sergienko, could you give me one single example/case of a piece of software which works/builds and suddenly would stop working/build because autoconf would suddenly support building with spaces in path ? And by the way, that can always be a fork project.