# SDL makefile missing seperator

Tags: c, linux, makefile, sdl

I downloaded [the SDL source](https://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). I extract the archive and run the configure script.

Upon trying to run make, I get `Makefile:255: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Here's the generated Makefile:

```
# Makefile to build and install the SDL library

top_builddir = .
srcdir  = /media/Media/linux apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10
objects = build
gen = gen
prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
bindir  = ${exec_prefix}/bin
libdir  = ${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir = ${prefix}/include
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
datadir = ${datarootdir}
auxdir  = build-scripts
distpath = $(srcdir)/..
distdir = SDL2-2.0.10
distfile = $(distdir).tar.gz


SHELL   = /bin/sh
CC      = gcc
INCLUDE = -I/media/Media/linux apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/include -idirafter /media/Media/linux apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/video/khronos
CFLAGS  = -g -O3 -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -I/media/Media/linux apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/include -idirafter /media/Media/linux apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/video/khronos 
LDFLAGS = 
EXTRA_LDFLAGS = 
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
AR  = ar
RANLIB  = ranlib
WINDRES = :

TARGET  = libSDL2.la
OBJECTS = /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/SDL_ime.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/SDL_threadprio.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo
GEN_HEADERS = 
GEN_OBJECTS = 
VERSION_OBJECTS = 

SDLMAIN_TARGET = libSDL2main.la
SDLMAIN_OBJECTS = /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo

SDLTEST_TARGET = libSDL2_test.la
SDLTEST_OBJECTS = /media/Media/linux $(objects)/*.lo

WAYLAND_SCANNER = 

INSTALL_SDL2_CONFIG = TRUE

SRC_DIST = *.txt acinclude Android.mk autogen.sh android-project build-scripts cmake cmake_uninstall.cmake.in configure configure.ac debian docs include Makefile.* sdl2-config.cmake.in sdl2-config.in sdl2.m4 sdl2.pc.in SDL2.spec.in SDL2Config.cmake src test VisualC.html VisualC VisualC-WinRT Xcode Xcode-iOS wayland-protocols
GEN_DIST = SDL2.spec

ifneq ($V,1)
RUN_CMD_AR     = @echo "  AR    " $@;
RUN_CMD_CC     = @echo "  CC    " $@;
RUN_CMD_CXX    = @echo "  CXX   " $@;
RUN_CMD_LTLINK = @echo "  LTLINK" $@;
RUN_CMD_RANLIB = @echo "  RANLIB" $@;
RUN_CMD_GEN    = @echo "  GEN   " $@;
LIBTOOL += --quiet
endif

HDRS = \
    SDL.h \
    SDL_assert.h \
    SDL_atomic.h \
    SDL_audio.h \
    SDL_bits.h \
    SDL_blendmode.h \
    SDL_clipboard.h \
    SDL_cpuinfo.h \
    SDL_egl.h \
    SDL_endian.h \
    SDL_error.h \
    SDL_events.h \
    SDL_filesystem.h \
    SDL_gamecontroller.h \
    SDL_gesture.h \
    SDL_haptic.h \
    SDL_hints.h \
    SDL_joystick.h \
    SDL_keyboard.h \
    SDL_keycode.h \
    SDL_loadso.h \
    SDL_log.h \
    SDL_main.h \
    SDL_messagebox.h \
    SDL_mouse.h \
    SDL_mutex.h \
    SDL_name.h \
    SDL_opengl.h \
    SDL_opengl_glext.h \
    SDL_opengles.h \
    SDL_opengles2_gl2ext.h \
    SDL_opengles2_gl2.h \
    SDL_opengles2_gl2platform.h \
    SDL_opengles2.h \
    SDL_opengles2_khrplatform.h \
    SDL_pixels.h \
    SDL_platform.h \
    SDL_power.h \
    SDL_quit.h \
    SDL_rect.h \
    SDL_render.h \
    SDL_rwops.h \
    SDL_scancode.h \
    SDL_sensor.h \
    SDL_shape.h \
    SDL_stdinc.h \
    SDL_surface.h \
    SDL_system.h \
    SDL_syswm.h \
    SDL_thread.h \
    SDL_timer.h \
    SDL_touch.h \
    SDL_types.h \
    SDL_version.h \
    SDL_video.h \
    SDL_vulkan.h \
    begin_code.h \
    close_code.h

SDLTEST_HDRS = $(shell ls $(srcdir)/include | fgrep SDL_test)

LT_AGE      = 10
LT_CURRENT  = 10
LT_RELEASE  = 2.0
LT_REVISION = 0
LT_LDFLAGS  = -no-undefined -rpath $(libdir) -release $(LT_RELEASE) -version-info $(LT_CURRENT):$(LT_REVISION):$(LT_AGE)

all: $(srcdir)/configure Makefile $(objects)/$(TARGET) $(objects)/$(SDLMAIN_TARGET) $(objects)/$(SDLTEST_TARGET)

$(srcdir)/configure: $(srcdir)/configure.ac
    @echo "Warning, configure is out of date, please re-run autogen.sh"

Makefile: $(srcdir)/Makefile.in
    $(SHELL) config.status $@

Makefile.in:;

$(objects)/.created:
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(objects)
    touch $@

update-revision:
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/updaterev.sh

.PHONY: all update-revision install install-bin install-hdrs install-lib install-data uninstall uninstall-bin uninstall-hdrs uninstall-lib uninstall-data clean distclean dist $(OBJECTS:.lo=.d)

$(objects)/$(TARGET): $(GEN_HEADERS) $(GEN_OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS) $(VERSION_OBJECTS)
    $(RUN_CMD_LTLINK)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=link $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(GEN_OBJECTS) $(VERSION_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(LT_LDFLAGS)

$(objects)/$(SDLMAIN_TARGET): $(SDLMAIN_OBJECTS)
    $(RUN_CMD_LTLINK)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=link $(CC) -static -o $@ $(SDLMAIN_OBJECTS) -rpath $(libdir)

$(objects)/$(SDLTEST_TARGET): $(SDLTEST_OBJECTS)
    $(RUN_CMD_LTLINK)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=link $(CC) -static -o $@ $(SDLTEST_OBJECTS) -rpath $(libdir)

install: all install-bin install-hdrs install-lib install-data
install-bin:
ifeq ($(INSTALL_SDL2_CONFIG),TRUE)
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    $(INSTALL) -m 755 sdl2-config $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/sdl2-config
endif

install-hdrs: update-revision
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2
    for file in $(HDRS) $(SDLTEST_HDRS); do \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 $(srcdir)/include/$$file $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/$$file; \
    done
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 include/SDL_config.h $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/SDL_config.h
    if test -f include/SDL_revision.h; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 include/SDL_revision.h $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/SDL_revision.h; \
    else \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 $(srcdir)/include/SDL_revision.h $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/SDL_revision.h; \
    fi

install-lib: $(objects) $(objects)/$(TARGET) $(objects)/$(SDLMAIN_TARGET) $(objects)/$(SDLTEST_TARGET)
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install $(INSTALL) $(objects)/$(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(TARGET)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install $(INSTALL) $(objects)/$(SDLMAIN_TARGET) $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(SDLMAIN_TARGET)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install $(INSTALL) $(objects)/$(SDLTEST_TARGET) $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(SDLTEST_TARGET)
install-data:
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/aclocal
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 $(srcdir)/sdl2.m4 $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/aclocal/sdl2.m4
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/pkgconfig
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sdl2.pc $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/pkgconfig
ifeq ($(INSTALL_SDL2_CONFIG),TRUE)
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/cmake/SDL2
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sdl2-config.cmake $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/cmake/SDL2
endif

uninstall: uninstall-bin uninstall-hdrs uninstall-lib uninstall-data
uninstall-bin:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/sdl2-config
uninstall-hdrs:
    for file in $(HDRS) $(SDLTEST_HDRS); do \
        rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/$$file; \
    done
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/SDL_config.h
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2/SDL_revision.h
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/SDL2
uninstall-lib:
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=uninstall rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(TARGET)
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(SDLMAIN_TARGET)
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(SDLTEST_TARGET)
uninstall-data:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/aclocal/sdl2.m4
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/pkgconfig/sdl2.pc
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake

clean:
    rm -rf $(objects)
    rm -rf $(gen)
    if test -f test/Makefile; then (cd test; $(MAKE) $@); fi

distclean: clean
    rm -f Makefile Makefile.rules sdl2-config
    rm -f config.status config.cache config.log libtool
    rm -rf $(srcdir)/autom4te*
    find $(srcdir) \( \
        -name '*~' -o \
        -name '*.bak' -o \
        -name '*.old' -o \
        -name '*.rej' -o \
        -name '*.orig' -o \
        -name '.#*' \) \
        -exec rm -f {} \;
    if test -f test/Makefile; then (cd test; $(MAKE) $@); fi

dist $(distfile):
    $(SHELL) $(auxdir)/mkinstalldirs $(distdir)
    (cd $(srcdir); tar cf - $(SRC_DIST)) | (cd $(distdir); tar xf -)
    tar cf - $(GEN_DIST) | (cd $(distdir); tar xf -)
    find $(distdir) \( \
        -name '*~' -o \
        -name '*.bak' -o \
        -name '*.old' -o \
        -name '*.rej' -o \
        -name '*.orig' -o \
        -name '.#*' \) \
        -exec rm -f {} \;
    if test -f $(distdir)/test/Makefile; then (cd $(distdir)/test && make distclean); fi
    (cd $(distdir); build-scripts/updaterev.sh)
    tar cvf - $(distdir) | gzip --best >$(distfile)
    rm -rf $(distdir)

rpm: $(distfile)
    rpmbuild -ta $?

# Build rules for objects
-include $(OBJECTS:.lo=.d)

# Special dependency for SDL.c, since it depends on SDL_revision.h
/media/Media/linux apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/SDL.c: update-revision
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/atomic/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/audio/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/cpuinfo/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/dynapi/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/events/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/file/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/haptic/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/joystick/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/libm/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/power/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/render/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/render/*/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/sensor/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/stdlib/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/thread/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/timer/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/video/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/video/yuv2rgb/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/video/dummy/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/audio/disk/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/audio/dummy/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/SDL_ime.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/core/linux/SDL_ime.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/joystick/linux/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/joystick/steam/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/power/linux/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/filesystem/unix/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/timer/unix/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/SDL_threadprio.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/core/linux/SDL_threadprio.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/core/unix/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/haptic/dummy/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/sensor/dummy/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/thread/generic/*.c $(objects)/.created  $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux
/*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/loadso/dummy/*.c $(objects)/.created    $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@

/media/Media/linux /*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/main/dummy/*.c $(objects)/.created   $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
/media/Media/linux /*.lo: apps/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10/src/test/*.c $(objects)/.created $(RUN_CMD_CC)$(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@
```

Line 255 seems to be:

```
/media/Media/linux
```

I tried tabbing in on that line, but that didn't seem to fix it.

A piece of info that might be relevant is the path seems incomplete. I have these in an external drive '/media/Media/linux\ apps'. I've never had an issue building apps on an external drive, is it the space in the folder name that's causing it to act strange?

Comment: What OS are you using? This is probably little comfort, but it compiles fine on my machine (Debian 10).

Comment: Maybe the directory with spaces give some trouble? "linux apps"

Comment: I am using VOID Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alex [has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776209/sdl-makefile-missing-seperator/58777534#comment103839382_58776209), make sure the path to the extracted source [doesn't have spaces in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194124/autoconf-spaces-in-path).

I repro'd the failure on a Debian Buster box:

```
user@host:~$ cd /tmp
user@host:/tmp$ wget https://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.10.tar.gz
user@host:/tmp$ mkdir "sdl space"
user@host:/tmp$ tar xvf SDL2-2.0.10.tar.gz -C "sdl space" --strip-components=1
user@host:/tmp$ cd "sdl space"
user@host:/tmp/sdl space$ ./configure
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
<snipped>
config.status: executing summary commands
SDL2 Configure Summary:
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries
Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick haptic sensor power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math   :
Audio drivers   : disk dummy pulse
Video drivers   : dummy vulkan
Input drivers   :
Using libsamplerate : NO
Using libudev       : NO
Using dbus          : NO
Using ime           : YES
Using ibus          : NO
Using fcitx         : NO
user@host:/tmp/sdl space$ make
Makefile:255: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Note the warning about Libtool right off the bat :)

Sadly SDL's CMake tooling doesn't behave any better, falling over during feature detection on the initial `cmake` invocation:

```
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_da3c6/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_da3c6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_da3c6.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/sdl space/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_da3c6.dir/HAVE_XEXT_H.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -g -O3 -idirafter /tmp/sdl space/src/video/khronos    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_da3c6.dir/HAVE_XEXT_H.c.o   -c "/tmp/sdl space/build/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_XEXT_H.c"
cc: error: space/src/video/khronos: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_da3c6.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_da3c6.dir/HAVE_XEXT_H.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/sdl space/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_da3c6/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: Every other app I've ever made has always worked in this path. I would really like to avoid having to remove the space and fix hundreds of other files that depend on it. Is there a way to force it to work with the directory with space in it? Like, an option / tag when running the configure script or something?